# Angular2 dragula model is not updated

Tags: model, angular, dragula

I am using ng2-dragula for my project and the model updating is not workin when drag and drop

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
   <li *ngFor="let item of itemList" [dragula]='"bag-one"'          [dragulaModel]='itemList' >
      <div >
           {{item.label | itemFilter:user.language}}
          <a (click)="delete(item)" style="cursor:pointer;">delete</a>
       </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

a part of my component :

```
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'item-user',
    templateUrl: 'item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['item.component.css'],
    pipes: [itemFilter],
    directives: [Dragula]
```

...

a part of my root component

```
@Component({
    .....
    viewProviders: [DragulaService]
```

the drag and drop works fine, put itemList (model) is not updated
(no error at console)
why ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to move the Dragula directives up to the "bag" level.

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;" [dragula]='"bag-one"' [dragulaModel]='itemList'>
   <li *ngFor="let item of itemList">
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it did not work because I was placing the dragula on html elements that were converting to shadow dom.

For example, I went from this:

```
<ion-card-content dragula="DRAGULA_FACTS">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let featureUserType of featureUserTypes">
    <uab-menu-feature-button [feature]="featureUserType"
                             [enableRoutes]="false"
                             [showDescription]="true"
                             [showFullName]="true"></uab-menu-feature-button>
  </ion-item>
```

To this:

```
<div [dragula]="'REORDER_FEATURES'"
       [dragulaModel]="featureUserTypes"
       (dragulaModelChange)="reorderFeatures($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let featureUserType of featureUserTypes">
      <ion-item>
        <uab-menu-feature-button [feature]="featureUserType"
                                 [enableRoutes]="false"
                                 [showDescription]="true"
                                 [showFullName]="true"></uab-menu-feature-button>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </div>
```